Overwrite exisiting storefront JavaScript plugin in Shopware 6
I am trying to overwrite an exisiting JavaScript plugin in Shopware 6. Unfortunately the code in the plugin file itself is not executed.
This is my main.js:
import MyCookiePermissionPlugin from './plugin/my-cookie-permission/my-cookie-permission.plugin';

const PluginManager = window.PluginManager;
PluginManager.override('CookiePermission', MyCookiePermissionPlugin, '[data-cookie-permission]');
console.log('test1');

and this is my my-cookie-permission.plugin.js:
import CookiePermissionPlugin from 'src/plugin/cookie/cookie-permission.plugin';

export default class MyCookiePermissionPlugin extends CookiePermissionPlugin {
    init() {
        console.log('test2');
        CookieStorage.setItem(this.options.cookieName, '');
        super.init();
    }

    _hideCookieBar() {
        if (confirm('Do you want to hide the cookie bar?')) {
            super._hideCookieBar();
        }
    }
}

When I now build the storefront and delete all the cookies and refresh the page, only the "test1" gets logged into the console, but "test2" is missing, even though that code should be executed when I see the Plugin Permission Bar of Shopware.
What am I doing wrong?

Which version of Shopware6 is it?

@AlexBerger Shopware Version 6.5.8.9

I tested your code and thats the result:

Edit: I added import CookieStorage from 'src/helper/storage/cookie-storage.helper'; to fix the error. Your code is working fine. I even get the confirm-message

Which Shopware Version are you using?
